# "Create new account" Block in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-forms

I am working on a drupal project where i in require a "Create new account" form on a content page. Can anybody help me out with this. Is there any module or any alternative to get "Create new account" as a block.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this question belongs to drupal answers website.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new module to add a custom block using [hook_block_info](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7) and [hook_block_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7).

Then use this code sample:

```
function yourmodule_block_info()
{
   $blocks = array();
   $blocks['my_registerform'] = array(
    'info' => t('Custom registration block'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
   );
   return $blocks
}


function yourmodule_block_view($delta = "")
{
    $block = array();

    if($delta = "my_registerform")
    {
        $form = drupal_get_form("user_register_form");
        $block['subject'] = t("Create new account");
        $block['content'] = drupal_render($form);
    }

    return $block;
}
```

After you enable this module, a new block is created that contains drupal's registration form. Go to the block manager page `admin/structure/block` to place it whenever you like.

Hope this helps.